# Can an oauthed cordova app auth a in-app webview?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, cordova, oauth

I have a cordova app that oauths into outside services like Facebook. Once authed, in some situations, the app will open facebook.com in an in-app browser to display the a post or message. But when navigating to Facebook.com/post/... the user is often asked to log in again; the webview isn't authorized...

Is there any way for the app, which is authorized, to inject the Facebook auth token into the web view somehow (cookie?) to avoid that login screen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the InAppBrowser plugin, you can get the url back from Facebook login.  The Facebook auth token should be a part of that.

Similar to whats happening here ([OpenFB](https://github.com/ccoenraets/OpenFB/blob/master/openfb.js)):

```
 /**
 * Called either by oauthcallback.html (when the app is running the browser) or by the loginWindow loadstart event
 * handler defined in the login() function (when the app is running in the Cordova/PhoneGap container).
 * @param url - The oautchRedictURL called by Facebook with the access_token in the querystring at the ned of the
 * OAuth workflow.
 */
function oauthCallback(url) {
    // Parse the OAuth data received from Facebook
    var queryString,
        obj;

    loginProcessed = true;
    if (url.indexOf("access_token=") > 0) {
        queryString = url.substr(url.indexOf('#') + 1);
        obj = parseQueryString(queryString);
        tokenStore['fbtoken'] = obj['access_token'];
        if (loginCallback) loginCallback({status: 'connected', authResponse: {token: obj['access_token']}});
    } else if (url.indexOf("error=") > 0) {
        queryString = url.substring(url.indexOf('?') + 1, url.indexOf('#'));
        obj = parseQueryString(queryString);
        if (loginCallback) loginCallback({status: 'not_authorized', error: obj.error});
    } else {
        if (loginCallback) loginCallback({status: 'not_authorized'});
    }
}
```

Comment: The oauth process isn't a problem. It's after oauth that I want to open a post or message on Facebook. At that point, even though the user is logged into my app (oauth), the in-app browser doesn't have the auth cookies, I'm guessing, so the user is presented with another login screen.